# Users fields are always empty using Tweepy Paginator APIv2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, paginator, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to pull tweets by keywords and collect information on the users to analyze the texts they posted, the following is my code:

```
def get_tweets(self, keywords, num_tweets):
    # Form a search query using all keywords
    query = " OR ".join(keywords) + " -is:retweet lang:en"

    # Define the fields to be returned in each Tweet object
    tweet_fields = ['id', 'text', 'created_at', 'lang', 'public_metrics', 'context_annotations', 'author_id']
    user_fields = ['username', 'description', 'location', 'verified']

    tweets = tweepy.Paginator(self.client.search_recent_tweets, 
                              query=query, 
                              expansions=['author_id'],
                              tweet_fields=tweet_fields,
                              user_fields=user_fields,
                              max_results=100).flatten(limit=num_tweets)
    
    tweet_data = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if 'includes' in tweet.data and 'users' in tweet.includes:
            users = {u["id"]: u for u in tweet.includes.get('users', [])}
            user = users.get(tweet.data['author_id'], {})
        else:
            user = {}
        
        tweet_data.append({
            'id': tweet.data['id'], 
            'username': user.get('username', ''), 
            'text': tweet.data['text'], 
            'created_at': tweet.data['created_at'], 
            'lang': tweet.data['lang'], 
            'public_metrics': tweet.data.get('public_metrics', ''), 
            'context_annotations': tweet.data.get('context_annotations', ''), 
            'description': user.get('description', ''),
            'location': user.get('location', ''),
            'verified': user.get('verified', ''),
        })

    # Convert the list of tweet data into a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(tweet_data)
    df.to_csv('tweetsf1.csv', index=False)
```

This is how I call the def to search by key terms:

```
# Pass a list of keywords to the function, TwitterClient is a class that includes token info
client = TwitterClient()

client.get_tweets(["test", "test app", \
                                         "test example"], \
                                        1000)
```

For some reason, all the fields under users are empty, such as username, description , location , and verified. This doesn't happen if I use client.get_tweet, but that will require too many requests , there are only 60 requests per every 15 mins, and it may require 4 hrs to pull 1000 tweets. I can only afford the basic plan.